# Deploying a .war made by Warbler to Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tomcat, jruby, war

I was trying to simply make a .war file and put it into Tomcat's webapps directory.  Simple, right? :)

What is puzzling me is that the directory structure of a JRuby app has the index.html file somewhere far in the application structure and Tomcat just can not find it by default.

Here is what I get when I point my url to the Tomcat install of the application:
http://128.48.204.195:8080/blog/index.html

How should I structure the build/deploy of a JRuby application so that it works on Tomcat when unwrapped out of a .war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try http://128.48.204.195/blog

that will serve the root route (if defined in config/routes.rb) or a error saying nor route.

If you see this: http://krokinet.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/rails-welcome1.png

there is a default index.html file in /public/index.html

that file is generated with the app and you should remove it once your done an initial 'smoke test' (running your newly generated app the first time).

More information on the root route here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root